# The Workplace self-evaluation: let's get critical!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, quality-evaluation

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

Comment: No no no, clearly a duplicate of http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/321/the-workplace-self-evaluation-lets-get-critical :P

Comment: @Rarity Oh you. :P

Comment: @AnnaLear Sheesh. All this self-evaluation! It's like SE has standards or something.

Comment: Heh, it appears I just serially downvoted you (I downvoted a lot of the answers here), hopefully the script is smart enough to not reverse my votes. Will check back in 24h, and if it does, I'll rant about it on MSO ;)

Answer (score 12):

[How to handle false allegations of my behavior and continue performing my job](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3065/how-to-handle-false-allegations-of-my-behavior-and-continue-performing-my-job)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Good question, good top answers (but quite a few bad answers and a few "could be comments" answers...)

Comment: Good question, some of the comments are redundant and some borderline offensive to some `Texas astounds me as a state` Did I say that?! ;-)

Comment: Comments could do with a cleanup, but good Q&A

Comment: This question represents a "real problem"; also, it is an interesting one that we should be proud to show on our top questions page.

Answer (score 10):

[What kinds of questions should I ask a recruiter?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3120/what-kinds-of-questions-should-i-ask-a-recruiter)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Excellent question and answers.  Prime example of what Workplace is about.

Answer (score 9):

[LinkedIn invitations from people I don't know](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3183/linkedin-invitations-from-people-i-dont-know)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: A good question, but some really good answers.

Comment: Also refreshing as it's about networking, but nice and specific and a question I think a lot of people have.

Comment: In this case, I believe what led to the great answers is the community dedication to the "back it up" rule. If that rule wasn't put in place, we just might have seen a lot of comments as answers and one-liners like the two downvoted posts at the bottom. IMHO, ***sometimes*** the answers make the question look great. +1

Answer (score 6):

[Software Development vs Technical Consulting](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3215/software-development-vs-technical-consulting)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I honestly feel this is too localized and an example of what we don't want people to see.  `I don't know which career to choose?  Choose my life for me!`  The answers are surprisingly good, but the question has a very black and white view of the world.

Comment: The intro makes it localised, but it's not really. And it's not so much "Choose my life for me" as "I am making a decision based on these assumptions. Are they correct?" I don't have a major problem with this one. Could maybe use some editing.

Comment: Considering this person didn't give a lot of specifics or details that would change over time, I'd say it's *not* too localized, and the answers seem to support this. +1

Comment: Given the comments here, it does indicate that some editing should probably happen, but that the heart of it is good.

Answer (score 6):

[Is it normal to list contractors on a corporate website?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3180/is-it-normal-to-list-contractors-on-a-corporate-website)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This is an extraordinary question and one that resonates with a very similar situation I was in recently.  I learned a lot from reading the answers.

Comment: Strange question, to me. Saved by an excellent top answer.

Comment: Not a question I'd ever have had, as the contractors I work with are in a very different situation than this case, so it was nice to see something productive and outside my "norm".

Comment: I do not care for the title but think it was a good question.

Answer (score 3):

[Getting fired for cause?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3095/getting-fired-for-cause)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I'm wary about these sorts of questions because of the possible severe legal implications of someone coming here, trusting the site as definitive, and then totally screw themselves over because they are in a different country. There was talk of potentially having a country tag for these sorts of questions (also questions relating to protocol/etiquette as varies by country)

Comment: @enderland Anybody that takes explicit legal advice from the internet deserves severe legal implications IMHO.  Most of us do a good job of calling out bad advice or specifically local advice.

Comment: I actually liked this in that instead of whining about injustice, the question was focused on actual actions and expectations for a situation that probably isn't unique to this individual.

Comment: I'm on the fence on this one. Legal questions are always sort of iffy in my opinion. When you ask a question like this, you're getting opinions from random people on the Internet. Being an expert in navigating the workplace setting is much different than being an expert in New York employment laws...

Comment: @jmort253 - There is some common(maybe uncommon) knowledge that goes around operating in the world.  One of these is a basic understanding of laws and rights.  Many of us learn them the hard way.  So long as the question is not asking for someone to take legal action you can ask about what a person can expect when they are fired.  Generally businesses will try to operate on the right side of the law.  Many times people expect protections that are not really there.  When there is something fishy we can advise to talk with a lawyer.

Comment: @Chad - After taking a second look at the answers, I'm convinced this question is a good example. +1. What saves it is that all answers mention "get a lawyer" as well as some good steps to help protect oneself.

Answer (score 3):

[How will management react if someone refuses a promotion?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3232/what-will-be-the-management-reaction-if-someone-refuses-a-promotion)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Very localized and hypothetical, but, with some work, could easily become a good question (probably too late now?)

Comment: It's never too late @enderland, just try to make sure the answers still make sense against the edits. :)

Comment: This is one of those questions that discuss a potential bait and switch scam that some employers play, although it isn't totally apparent by reading the question.  The answers bring a lot of insight into the reality of the situation with the person asking the question.

Comment: I felt like this was in the collection of questions that walks the borderline - there's a lot in here that just may be so specialized that it only helps the asker.  But I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2):

[Team building activities for a fast growing team](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3105/team-building-activities-for-a-fast-growing-team)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Weird, I actually down voted on something I started. :)  I really don't know what happened with the answers here - I though (even at the outset) that I was pretty specific in what I asked for, but the answere were all over the map and in the end, very few actually filled my need.

Comment: This is sort of a polling question in disguise, IMHO, asking for a list of event types to fit a specific need. Even though Beth says she didn't get the answers she wanted, community dedication to providing details, as well as Beth asking the community to "describe in detail" sort of saved this and suppressed the polling aspect quite well! IMHO, the top answer solves the problem: "Talk to the team ... challenge them to come up with something". This not only solves the problem for Beth, but for any future visitor who wants to hold any kind of event for any kind of department... +1

Comment: @bethlakshmi - That is the problem with list questions.  I think it was left open more out of respect for the immense good you bring to the site than because it was a good question.

Comment: Fair enough.  Thanks for the kudos, but I'll close the question.

Answer (score 1):

[What can I do to hire people in the tech field who are knowledgeable and personable?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3155/what-can-i-do-to-hire-people-in-the-tech-field-who-are-knowledgeable-and-persona)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Relatively ok question, difficult to answer definitively (and there are books upon books written on this subject) but easy to give good answers to. imo the accepted answer was not the best answer

Comment: Poor question turned ok by some savvy edits. But only ok. Answers didn't improve it.

Comment: Not, IMO, one of our better ones. Not (by any stretch) our worst, either, so after waffling, I didn't vote either way, figuring what I dislike (the generic quality of the question) was outweighed by the insightfulness of some of the answers.

Comment: The generic aspect to the question was probably due to my edit. On some sites I contribute to, if you leave in "what resources are there for X", people will sometimes leave comments as answers with nothing but a link.  A question is always going to be better if the op can edit it instead of some random third party, since the op knows what she or he is wanting to solve. Still, editing can go a long way, and I think this got some great answers.

Comment: Another list question :(  This really needed to be edited to be brought on point before answers came in.

Answer (score -7):

[Negotiation for Fulltime Conversion After Internship](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3245/negotiation-for-fulltime-conversion-after-internship)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Too many questions in one. Answers ended up unreadably long.

Comment: @pdr agreed, more than two sub-questions is often a red flag, I think this is a good example of why.

Comment: Plus, when you have multiple topics in one post, some people don't cover all the questions, making it harder to vote on the answers. There's only two though, likely because it's a bit overwhelming. I voted to close as "Too localized". Great points in the comments about this making 5 really awesome separate questions though!

Comment: Amazingly while this answer is at -7, the question it's about is at +3, with only one downvote (mine). Nice, we apparently hate the question, but I guess it wouldn't be "nice" to downvote it, it's "nicer" to let it appear as a useful question... <sigh>

Comment: To be fair, I tried to get it closed when I realized it was a bad question but it wasn't closed until VERY recently ;-)